# Sendmail and non ASCII characters in adresses

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail

Does anybody know of plans for support of EAI and SMTPUTF8 in sendmail? I could find very little about it.

On the same note, does anybody know if sendmail's development is alive/dead/comatose? The home site does not offer many hints.

P.S: please hold the "run XXX instead of sendmail" advice. I know about the alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions some patch for sendmail.

Comment: I may have missed that WP bit. I see this (https://github.com/arnt/sendmail-smtputf8) exists on github, but I have no clue on its state.

Comment: My knowledge about this patch is pretty fresh too.